# How to create file type custom data with API?

Tags: custom-fields

I was wondering how to do that. Didn't find it for that type of custom data.

If possible I want to do it via API, if not possible i'll try with CRM_Core files.

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the API to create/upload a file at the server?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom group with the CustomGroup API, and custom fields with the CustomField API. Is that what you mean, or do you mean updating the actual data within a custom file?

Comment: Sorry my english's probably bad... I'm trying to say that I want to create a new line in the database. CustomGroup and CustomField already exists. What I need is to create a new "object" through the API to save it in the database.

Comment: It depends on the entity your are adding too in my experience. I think for example for the Contact entity, you can add something like custom_25='yourvalue' to the Contact Create param set. In theory you can also use the CustomValue API but that is a bit of a beast...So I tend to use CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery() if I can not use the entity API. Let me know if this helps you or if you are not aware of the CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery method

Comment: I know about CRM_Core_DAO functions and some of others Core functions. Thing is I wanted a "simple" way to store files through the API. If nothing exists right now I will just do is with CRM_Core functions. Anyway thank's a lot for your help !

Comment: You might want to try with the CustomValue API? Perhaps I am exaggerating....

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [Attachment api](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/changes/#460-attachment-api). Use the API explorer on your own Civi site to see available parameters for this api.